# Switch between Java 32-bit and Java 64-bit

Tags: java, tomcat

I have just found out that Apache Tomcat cannot run as a Windows service if I'm using a 64-bit JDK. Therefore I have additionally installed Java 32-bit on my Windows.

The question is when I checked the java version using java -version, it still shows that 64-bit is still running. How do you switch from 64-bit to 32-bit? It would also be nice to have the ability to switch back to 64-bit later as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The question is when I checked the java version using java -version, it still shows that 64-bit is still running.

That's not strictly true.  There is no copy of Java still / already running.  (Or if there is, you aren't talking to *it* when you run `java -version`.)

What this *actually* shows is that your command shell runs a 64-bit Java when you gave it the command name `java`.  And the reason for that is that shell's %PATH% variable is telling the shell to look in the directory containing the 64-bit version, rather than the 32-bit version; i.e. you haven't changed it!

What you need to do is to change the shell's %PATH% and %JAVA_HOME% environment variables to point to the correct place.  The %JAVA_HOME% should point to the installation directory, and the %PATH% variable should include %JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Comment: *%PATH% variable should include %JAVA_HOME%\bin.* this wont help on Windows, it's correct for Linux, though. On Windows java is started from the %WINDIR%, so altering PATH will have zero effect. Instead tomcat script should be instructed to start java from the designated location.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to the path of the JDK version you want to use.

For 2000/XP see: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

For Windows 7 see: http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html (this is not a tutorial to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable, but a generic environment variable: please adapt to your needs.)

If you want to change the Java version you see when running `java -version` on the command line, then you have to change the `PATH` environment variable so that it contains a path to the `bin` directory of the JDK you want to use. See: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml
Remember to close the command shell and re-open it after you change the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I found that on Windows 7, I had to edit the `JAVA_HOME` path in the registry entries in multiple places in order to *completely* switch to a different path for another java installation. Changing `JAVA_HOME` in the environment variables is not enough. You can do a quick test yourself:

1. Rename your Java Home directory.
2. Update your `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable value to reflect the
   new name of your `JAVA_HOME`.
3. Run `java -version` in a new command window.

You will get an error message saying

```
Error: could not open `C:\your_java_home_path\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Therefore, it's not the same behavior as on Linux where simply changing `$JAVA_HOME` is enough to change your pointer to a new installation directory of your java.

Looks like Windows hard codes the java home path in its registry in multiple places.

```
Start --> Run --> regedit
```

Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SOFTWARE / JavaSoft / ...`
expand each directory and edit every java home path that you find hard coded to your new `JAVA_HOME` path in each registry where it occurs.

Comment: -1. This behavior is because your path contained another reference to your old java installation. If you fixed your path, this wouldn't have been an issue.